# How to check radio based on model custom value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-value

I'm trying to use the example code from this [Angularjs example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) page in my app for input[radio]. I choose to use an object as a value of a particular radio button, so each of the radio buttons in a group has a value of some object.

In the [plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/B9Ma6A1oOPvfrCSAoini?p=preview), if you set the model to green which is:

```
$scope.color = {
  name: 'green'
};
```

The proper radio button is not checked by default. I think its because the value of this radio button is an object.

Any ideas how to make it work? How do I check the proper radio button if its value is an object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the model `$scope.color.name` to the "green" object which is defined in the `ngValue` directive:

```
$scope.specialValue = {
  id: '12345',
  value: 'green'
};

$scope.color = {
  name: $scope.specialValue
};
```

Because it's `ngValue` directive is bound to `specialValue`

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="specialValue">
  Green
</label>
```

Here is a [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/V1jvCvCuCDW3G8JPKwFS?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-radio-input-directive-production</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="radioExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('radioExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.specialValue = {
        "id": "12345",
        "value": "green"
      };
      $scope.color = {
        name: $scope.specialValue
      };
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="red">
    Red
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="specialValue" checked=checked>
    Green
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="blue">
    Blue
  </label><br/>
  <tt>color = {{color.name | json}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
 Note that `ng-value="specialValue"` sets radio item's value to be the value of `$scope.specialValue`.
</body>
</html>

<!-- 
Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
-->
```